# App crashes when in UITableview delete row very fast and go back to previous view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 simple view (ViewController and TableviewController), from first view show second view. In second view (Tableview) showing list of array. When I'm deleting row in Tableview very fast and immediately go to back (first view), app crashing with error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d6bc7ef8 0x1d5d95a40 0x1d6b3d85c 0x1d6aace20 0x203afaa44 0x203acf4f8 0x203acf694 0x203aea3f4 0x203afa900 0x203c6ba34 0x203afa840 0x203af8dbc 0x20357a544 0x203580da4 0x2035811dc 0x203581e5c 0x20402c3c8 0x203c6ce68 0x203c42ee4 0x203c434d0 0x1db1bb394 0x104a84de4 0x104a92a94 0x1d6b561bc 0x1d6b51084 0x1d6b505b8 0x1d8dc4584 0x2035cb558 0x102452290 0x1d6610b94)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

[Gif screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYwho.gif)

My code:

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items = ["Apple", "Samsung", "Xiaomi", "Huawei", "Oppo", "Vivo"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I delete row and wait for a while (0.4-1 sec) or reload table view after deleting have not any crashing.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData() //After adding this line didn't handle any crashing
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: As same as @Carpsen90, cannot reproduce it so far...

Comment: @Carpsen90 you should delete row and very fast (between 0.1-0.6 sec) go back to previous view, better use real device not simulator for reproduce it.

Comment: @AhmadF I think this problem is actual, because I check some app from App Store have same problem.

Comment: I did use a real device. What do you mean by "*go back to previous view*"? You mean dismiss the current view controller?

Comment: My versions: Xcode 10, swift 4, iOS 12, iPhone 8 plus

Comment: Not even with embedding in a navigation controller and tapping the back button really fast. Maybe you have some tweaks on your phone that are messing things up.

Comment: @Carpsen90 have two view first view embedded Navigation Controller and add simple button for showing second TableView. From Tableview delete row and immediately click "Back" button on Navigation Controller or swipe right for going to first view (Standart Swipe Gesture) app crashing.

Comment: @Carpsen90 but when I commented 'tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)' crashing stop

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Unable to produce this error. Please share the video.There is no issue with code

Comment: It does crash, if you delete a row with fade animation and click a row very fast whilst the other row is being deleted it goes out of bounds, but this doesnt solve it!